# Translate little part only on website using Google or Bing

Tags: translate

I need to translate only a small part on my website using google translate or bing.
It's in German and for german people, but a small part of text on specific pages are in other languages. And i need an option where German people can translate this to german by pressing a button or so.
I can only find solutions on translation the entire site.
Example:

This is in german and must be kept that way

This is in english or another language and should be translated if button clicked

.

Bsically i dunno how to tell google / bing, that only some of it should be translated.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend for specific phrase detection to either use an open source product like Jquery Globalize Library.

https://github.com/jquery/globalize

If you want a fully serviced/hosted solution that removes any need to hard code these translations check out

https://localizejs.com/

We help make developers set and forget the pains of localization by automating as much of the process for you.

Comment: short answer googles API does not allow for free translations anymore.  Google/Bing translate all content/

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will allow you to translate individual sections of your site or the entire page. You have to provide the translation for each phrase into each target language but you can do that by translating them in Google or Bing as you suggested and then use the plugin to allow your visitors to translate the text on demand:

https://github.com/coolbloke1324/jquery-lang-js

That plugin has language persistence across pages, allows both phrase and regex-based matching, can handle any number of language options and allows you to trigger the change from a click event as you described.

You can see it being used live on https://www.orbzu.com (look top-left of the page for the flag icon and then select a new language to see the text on the page change automatically).